# Google Scripts Trigger not firing Automatically

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the trigger set up to run this script, "Time-Driven", on a "day timer" between "11 pm-12 midnight". I'm getting no failure notifications (set up to email to me immediately), but the script isn't running. It works exactly as I want it to when I manually run it, but the whole point was to automate it, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. Whole purpose of this to Auto Run. Please help me to find the issue and how to trigger automatically?

```
`function convertExcelSiemenstoGoogleSheet(fileName) {
  var sheetid = '';
  try {
                // var sshet = DriveApp.getFilesByName("");
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('1l_9ZFwEmVl8Mas975bEPPhUTEcei9-Nf'); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  
var fileIterator = fSource.getFilesByName('1. Rem');
if (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
  var fileList = fileIterator.next();
  sheetid = fileList.getId();
  Logger.log(fileList.getId());
} else {
  // Handle the case when the file is not found
  Logger.log("File not found");
  return; // or throw an error or take appropriate action
}



while (fSource.getFilesByName('1. Rem').hasNext()) {
  var fileList = fSource.getFilesByName('1. Rem').next();
                //var fileList = DriveApp.getFilesByName('12.Rem').next();
                //    var folderId = Drive.Files.get("1l_9ZFwEmVl8Mas975bEPPhUTEcei9-Nf").parents[0].id;
  var sheetid = '';
  //Logger.log(fileList.length);
  
                //while (fileList.hasNext()) {
  sheetid = fileList.getId();
  //Logger.log(fileList.getId());
                //}
}
    var BCON = Lastrow(sheetid);
    //Logger.log("Bcon="+BCON);
    fileName = fileName || "1. Rem.xlsx";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = Drive.Files.get("1HEU_gKo-Lj4N0n0E1zotbLQeP5BDhvTq", {supportsAllDrives: true}).title;//.parents[0].id;
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    
    var resource = {
      title: excelFile.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      parents: [{id: "1l_9ZFwEmVl8Mas975bEPPhUTEcei9-Nf"}],
      
    };
    //Logger.log(resource);
    //Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    let spreadsheet = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    //Drive.Files.remove(sheetid);
  
    var ACON= Lastrow(spreadsheet.id);
    //Logger.log("Acon="+ACON);
    var diff= ACON-BCON;

    if (diff>0){
    var recipients1 = "xxxxxx.com";
    var recipients2 = "xxxxxx.ccom";
    var recipients3 = "xxxxxx.com";
    
    var subject = 'XXXXXX - Partnership Sheet Updates  [ ' +diff +" Rows Updated]";
    var body = 'Rows Added TODAY = '+diff;

    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients1, subject, body);
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients2, subject, body);
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients3, subject, body);
    }
    
  } 
  
  catch(f)  {
 Logger.log(f.toString());
  //console.log(f.message, f.stack );
 }



function Lastrow(shtid) {
//Logger.log("sheet="+shtid);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(shtid)
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Partnership')
var lrow = sh.getLastRow();
var Avals = sh.getRange("B1:B"+lrow).getValues();
var Alast  = lrow - Avals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');

//Logger.log("lrow"+lrow+" =Avals  "+Avals+ "Alast="+Alast);
return Alast;
}
}
```

Comment: `between "11 pm-12 noon"` There is no trigger "time of day" = "11 pm-12 noon". Would you please check the "time of day" and edit your question. If you installed the trigger programmatically, I suggest that you check the status manually.

Comment: Any idea why its not triggering automatically?

Comment: Qn#1: Please correct me if I am wrong, your script `convertExcelSiemenstoGoogleSheet` is installed as a time-driven trigger to run between 11pm and 12 midnight. In the Project Editor "Triggers" tab, the "Last run" column is blank for this script. In the "Executions" tab, the script is only ever shown as executed with Type = "Event" and never with Type = Time-Driven". Qn#2: The function takes an argument: when you run the function manually do you supply an argument. Qn#3: Do you have any other triggers running which affect this function?

Comment: In order to assist further, trouble shooting is required. I suggest: delete the existing trigger and install a time-driven trigger for, say, every 1 minute (enough for script to execute, and for you to observe execution). The goal is simply to confirm that the function is/can be being triggered.

Comment: I have deleted and tried with Time driven trigger every minute. there is "Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end." , but when i run this code by clicking manual run ,, i am receiving the email what i wanted. not working by itself

Comment: `Would you please response to my earlier questions:` Qn#1: Please correct me if I am wrong, your script convertExcelSiemenstoGoogleSheet is installed as a time-driven trigger to run between 11pm and 12 midnight. In the Project Editor "Triggers" tab, the "Last run" column is blank for this script. In the "Executions" tab, the script is only ever shown as executed with Type = "Event" and never with Type = Time-Driven". Qn#2: The function takes an argument: when you run the function manually do you supply an argument. Qn#3: Do you have any other triggers running which affect this function?

Comment: The time-driven script is failing on `var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();`. In short, this is because the script interprets `fileName` as an event object. Typically an event object is called "e" but "fileName" works just as well. When executed manually `fileName = fileName || "1. Rem.xlsx"` returns a value of `1. Rem.xlsx`. BUT when triggered this returns `[object Object]` - this is the [event objects for a time-driven event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events).

Comment: For the above message, Answers :- An#1 Yes Given Time-Driven trigger to run between 11pm and 12 midnight,  In the Project Editor "Triggers" tab, the "Last run" is not blank, also in the "Executions" tab the Type = "Time-Driven". An#2 No we don't supply an argument.. An#3. NO